# NodeJS - how to create a JSON file with an array inside in a specified format?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json

I would like to achieve this JSON structure:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "surname": "Green"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jessica",
      "surname": "Morgan"
    },
    ...
}
```

I am trying to do it like this:

```
People({}).sort('-createdAt').exec(function(err, people) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(people);

        let data = {}
        data['people'] = [];
        data.push(people);
        res.json(data);
    });
```

When I look at the generated JSON structure, it is in this format:

```
{
    "people": [
        [
            {
               "name": "Peter",
               "surname": "Green"
            },
            ...
```

In the JSON, there are two arrays in the `people` section. How do I get rid one of the array from there?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're reading from a database, and it looks like it's returning an array of people.

Try not pushing it into a new array?

```
People({}).sort('-createdAt').exec(function(err, people) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(people);

        let data = {
            people: people
        };
        res.json(data);
    });
```

Comment: Or simply use res.json({ people });

Comment: Correct (gave you an upvote).  I am always a little careful about using more advanced syntax when answering a question.